# Combinations of Colored Marbles

Tags: combinatorics

A jar contains 8 red marbles and 5 white marbles.

a) How many ways can I pick two red marbles?

b) How many ways can I pick one red and one white?

Solutions:

a) Since order doesn't matter I thought it would be ${8 \choose 2}$ but the answer is 8*7. Why do the two approaches differ? Why can't I just use ${8 \choose 2}$

b) I initially thought it would be ${8 \choose 1}{5 \choose 1}$ but the answer is 2*8*5.
We are taking into account the fact the number of combinations of RW and WR. Why doesn't ${8 \choose 1}{5 \choose 1}$ work?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly in this case, all marbles are distinguishable (imagine they are numbered) and the order matters (imagine they are arranged on a shelf). This should have perhaps been made clearer to you in the question. Otherwise your solutions would have been fine (using your understanding).

Comment: What if the marbles are all identical?

Comment: @Jessica Then in that case your answer is correct. The problem here is that you can identify the marbles. Picking Marble no. 1 after Marble no.2 is different from vice versa.

Comment: Assuming the marbles are identical and order doesn't matter. Why do the two solutions differ?

Comment: The two solutions differ because only your solution would be correct in that case.